# Easiest (cleanest/seamless) way to migrate from Thunderbird to Office 2010

Tags: email, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010, migration

We moved to Thunderbird a few years ago. It was a good decision back then, we still don't have any regrets about it. Thunderbird was improving during these years, we had no problems. Things were good.

As Mozilla announced their sudden change of plans, we would like to move back to Outlook (2010).
What is the easiest, cleanest, and most seamless way of doing this?

(We would need: contacts, mails (from all folders) and configurations.)
Extra bits of information:
- We are using Windows 7 64-bit (Professional SP1) on our machines.
- And the latest Thunderbird: 13.0.1

If you need any information or you want to ask a question, feel free. Comment.

Comment: Why Outlook instead of Evolution?

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5924072/thunderbird-to-slow-down-development-focus-on-security-and-stability-only | http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/258975/mozilla_puts_the_brakes_on_thunderbird.html#tk.rss_news

Comment: Of course there is nothing wrong with that. Mozilla is not Google. Sad thing they don't realize that. They don't have the same amount of money, or the same amount of people. Yet they have so many projects under their hand. Yes the development is open-source... but how many people will code and write patches? (You know what I'm talking about.) || tl;dr: The time has come, projects will get a cut. Thunderbird is just a single victim in the long line. But there are alternatives out there, so it's not the end of the world or anything.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: if you meant Evolution as in Gnome's Evolution (mail client)... it may run "OK" under Linux, but running Gnome stuff under Windows for example, is a terrible experience. (On the other hand, one could consider "Claws" or "Sylpheed". But we went with Office anyway, the people already know how to use it.)

Comment: I've commented on a similar question, moving the other way. An IMAP server is the most effective way to do this, because the messages are preserved almost 100% perfectly. Exporting and importing comes with some risks, in many cases deal-breakers. You can use Exchange or a free IMAP server as a temporary intermediary, upload the messages, and then download them again in Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/) to transfer  your Thunderbird messages into Outlook. You just need to select the source folders in Thunderbird and the target folder in Outlook.

MailExporter can only transfer the email messages.

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)